# HAML helper in Rails to create javascript:void(0) links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

How can I define a helper for HAML in Rails to define links with `href='javascript:void(0)'`?

i.e. a shorthand for this:

```
%a.link#somelink(href="javascript:void(0)") Link to Foo
```

Hopefully neater than this:

```
- js_link {:class=>'link', :id=>'somelink'} "Link to Foo"
```

I mean a HAML helper, not a traditional Rails helper. I hoping for something like:

```
%js.link#somelink Link to Foo
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going to have a hard time with this. The simplest you could make it would probably be something like

```
#somelink.link
  - js_link 'Link to Foo'
```

But this would add the `id` and `class` attributes to a div surrounding your link rather than directly on it. If the selectors are for CSS or jQuery purposes, you might get away with leaving the attributes off altogether and using the surrounding element information to access the links:

```
#list-of-links
  %a{href: "javascript:void(0);"}
  %a{href: "javascript:void(0);"}
  %a{href: "javascript:void(0);"}
```

And in JavaScript:

```
jQuery('#list-of-links a').on('click', function() { return doSomething(); });
```

All this being said, it is possible to create a [custom filter](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Filters.html), similar to `:css` or `:script` for Haml with something like

```
Haml::Filters.register_tilt_filter "JavaScriptLink"
```

But for this to work, you would have to define your own `"JavaScriptLink"` [Tilt](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt) template system, and even then, I'm not sure it would work or look any prettier.